# Minutes to hours

Tags: excel, vba

When i write for example 7,3 or 7,30 the intended result is 7,5 and this works fine until 7,49 but when i reach 7,5 the added decimal part somehow becomes negative and the result makes even less sense which is 7,16666666666667

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        .Value = CInt(.Value) + ((.Value - CInt(.Value)) / 0.6)
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

What is happening...

Comment: This looks like some attempt of rounding, but it is unclear what you really want to do, because none of the variables you use here seem to have to do anything with time.

Comment: 7,30 (7.30 in the US) is intended to represent 7 hours and 30 mins. The formula converts 7,30 to 7,5 (7.5 US) to represent the value in hours shown as a true decimal number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the fractional part of expression is exactly .5, CInt always rounds it to the nearest even number. For example, .5 rounds to 0, and 1.5 rounds to 2.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/vb-net-language/0596000928/re40.html

Use Int() instead of CInt():

```
.Value = Int(.Value) + ((.Value - Int(.Value)) / 0.6)
```

Or maybe Fix():

```
.Value = Fix(.Value) + ((.Value - Fix(.Value)) / 0.6)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions